# Symmetry in the solution of orbit equation in central force

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, orbital-motion, differential-equations, time-reversal-symmetry

In Goldstein's Classical Mechanics, following comment is made regarding the equation of orbit in central force:

> $\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}+u=-\frac{m}{l^2}\frac{d}{du}V\Big(\frac{1}{u}\Big)\tag{3.34}$
> The preceding equation is such that the resulting orbit is symmetrical about two adjacent turning points. To prove this statement, note that if the orbit is symmetrical it should be possible to reflect it about the direction of the turning angle without producing any change. If the coordinates are chosen so that the turning point occurs for $\theta=0$, then the reflection can be effected mathematically by substituting $-\theta$ for $\theta$. The differential equation for the orbit $(3.34)$, is obviously invariant under such a substitution. Further the initial conditions, here
> $u=u(0),\;\Big(\frac{du}{d\theta}\Big)_o=0,\;for\;\theta=0$ will likewise be unaffected.

If we take the turning point to be at $\theta=0$, then the above symmetry in solution suggests that $u(\theta)=u(-\theta)$.
I am not able to prove how the differential equation $(3.34)$ suggests that if $u(\theta)=u(-\theta)$ (or $u(\theta)$ is an even function). We don't know the form of $V(\frac{1}{u})$, then how can we make such a generalized statement?
Actually I have just started studying about the differential equations. I don't know whether this symmetry in the solution arises directly from the form of differential equation. So please don't mind if it is a silly question.
Please help me in proving this fact.

Comment: Obviously is that for $\theta\mapsto -\theta$ die differential equation remaining unchanged. Can you proof it ?

Comment: @Eli, thanks for the reply. May you please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the  differential equation
$$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}+u=-\frac{m}{l^2}\frac{d}{du}V\Big(\frac{1}{u}\Big)\tag 1$$

take $u(\theta)\mapsto u(-\theta)$

$$\frac{du}{d\theta}\,\mapsto-\frac{du}{d\theta}~~~,
\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}\mapsto \frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}$$
thus equation (1)  $~\mapsto$
$$\frac{d^2u(-\theta)}{d\theta^2}+u(-\theta)=-\frac{m}{l^2}\frac{d}{du}V\Big(\frac{1}{u(-\theta)}\Big)\tag 2$$

equation (2) is equal equation (1)

**Edit**

$$y=u(f(\theta))\\
\frac{d y}{d\theta}=\frac{d}{d\theta}\,u(f(\theta))\frac{d f}{d\theta}$$

with $~f(\theta)=-\theta~$

$$\frac{d y}{d\theta}=\frac{d}{d\theta}\,u(-\theta)\,(-1)$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In your edit shouldn't, $\frac{dy}{d\theta}=\frac{du(f(\theta))}{df(\theta)}\frac{df}{d\theta}=\frac{du(-\theta)}{d(-\theta)}\frac{d(-\theta)}{d\theta}=-\frac{du(-\theta)}{d(-\theta)}$

Comment: Why $\frac{du(-\theta)}{d(-\theta)}=\frac{du(\theta)}{d\theta}$? May you please explain this.

Comment: \begin{align*}
 &\text{lets say that u is a function of $~x^2~$ thus}\\
 &y=u(x^2)\\
 & \text{what is the derivative $~\frac{dy}{dx}~$ ?}\\
 & \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}\,2x \quad,
\text{not}\,~
\frac{du}{dx^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi Eli, in equation 2 is $u=u(-\theta)$ ?

Comment: I.e  your second equation is :$$\frac{d^2u(-\theta) }{d\theta^2}+u(-\theta)
   =-\frac{m}{l^2}\frac{d}{du}V\Big(\frac{1}{u (-\theta)   }\Big)$$

Comment: Do you mean that i should put the argument , i will do it thanks

Comment: Your answer helped me. +10 :)

Comment: I had a related doubt can we have a chat?

Comment: We can try but we can’t write equations?

Comment: @kashmiri  if Eq. (2) is correct $\frac{d^2u(-\theta)}{d\theta^2}+u(-\theta)=-\frac{m}{l^2}\frac{d}{du}V\Big(\frac{1}{u(-\theta)}\Big)~$ then substitute $~u(-\theta)=v~,du=dv~$ and you obtain the differential equation (1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130877/discussion-between-kashmiri-and-eli).